# Using foreach loop to update MySQL table with array of IDs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to update a MySQL table with three columns (id, franchise_id, state_id) with data from an array by using a foreach loop. The table updates but the four rows that match the franchise_id are being updated with the last item in the array (4). I can't figure out where the error is.

Data passed to the function:

```
$states = [1,2,3,4];
$franchise_id = 5;
```

The update function:

```
public static function update($franchise_id, $states)
{

    try
    {
        // establish db connection
        $db = static::getDB();

        $sql = "UPDATE franchise_states SET state_id = ? WHERE franchise_id = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        foreach($states as $state)
        {
            $stmt->execute([$state, $franchise_id]);
        }
        return $stmt;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
       echo "Error updating franchise data: " . $e->getMessage();
       exit();
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: well, because that's what you do. What would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's updating for all the values in $states array but the last one stays because, well, it is the last executed one.

You try to update state_id against the same value `franchise_id=5` and since all of them has the same franchise id, the last value stays.

Comment: Thanks. I need a row for each different state_id. A franchise_id can appear many times. Sort of like a lookup table. Do you have a suggestion how to do this?

Comment: then don't do an update, but an insert. First check if that combination (same state & franchise) already exists. But if a franchise can have all 4 states, then there's something wrong in the logic, isn't it? (unless you mean geografical states)

Comment: I agree with @Jeff. You can always put a unique composite index on state_id and franchise_id to avoid duplicate insertions.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Yes, I mean geographical states. One franchise_id can be in 50 rows with 50 different state_ids. I will give this a try and report back. Thanks!

Comment: While researching this I found a possible remedy might include adding a constraint to the table:  `ALTER TABLE franchise_states ADD CONSTRAINT fs_unique UNIQUE (id, franchise_id, state_id);`

Comment: remove the id from the constraint! (only franchise combined with state is enough)

Comment: Yes this will avoid collisions on same state and same franchise id if you remove the id column from the index. But it will not solve your problem as your query, like @Jeff suggested, should have been an insert

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I didn't add that constraint; merely referencing it. I have a foreign key constraint connecting this table with the ``franchises`` table, and when I just ran `INSERT INTO` its throwing an error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: You are don't have a record on `franchises` table which constraints to franchise id = 5

Comment: I just got it to work. It added new rows so I have some duplication, but I can fix that. The main thing was getting this to work, and it does. Not sure how I can post the modified function.

Comment: @Cemal. Here's the constraint:  `CONSTRAINT `FK_franchise_states` FOREIGN KEY (`franchise_id`) REFERENCES `franchises` (`franchise_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: No need to post it, as your question was something else. The answer above replies that. These comments fixed your latter problems

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Like a man needs his upvotes, a question needs an accepted answer:) glad to help mate. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Have you try to edit this line?

```html
foreach($states as $state)
```

to

```html
foreach($state as $states)
```

Comment: First, this is just wrong: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) expects the first element to be an array or array expression, in your case `$state` would need to be defined and be an array, both is not the case. Second, you don't give any explanation as why the author should change his code to yours. Please don't guess and only answer if you know what you are talking about.

Comment: I downvoted this because this is completely wrong. 

  1. it's wrong according to code, as foreach requires the first parameter to be implemented by either IteratorAggregate or Iterator.

  2.) The answer is wrong, as the answer has nothing to do with the problem, the problem is about the query not the foreach loop.